# SCP made for blocking non MFA users is blocking other AWS actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

I have a SCP attached to my root account which should disable users without MFA to do most actions but instead this SCP blocks other AWS actions between services such as, I am not able to create an AWS Backup, I have confirmed that it is this policy indeed which is blocking Backup to create Backups. Below is the policy that I am using.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "BlockMostAccessUnlessSignedInWithMFA",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotAction": [
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
        "iam:ListAccountAliases",
        "iam:ListUsers",
        "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
        "iam:ListAccessKeys",
        "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
        "iam:ListMFADevices",
        "iam:GetAccountSummary",
        "sts:GetSessionToken"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have also tried adding "aws:ViaAWSService": "false" into the policy as some AWS documentations mentioned that, but this did not solved the issue as well.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This blocks all unmentioned actions because you've removed the default FullAWSAccess statement from the SCP. You need an Allow/*/* statement *plus* your Deny statement to allow all actions but deny specific IAM actions in the absence of MFA.

Answer (score 2):

This SCP policy denies access to all services (Except the included API's) unless and MFA authenticate session is passed. Now, when we apply this policy as an SCP, IAM Users and Root users can create an MFA Authenticated session, but IAM Roles assumed by a service cannot. Similarly, an EC2 instance cannot create an MFA authenticates session while assuming an IAM Role.

We can deny certain API actions unless an MFA authenticate session is used ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps_examples_general.html#example-scp-mfa ), but if you wish to force MFA for IAM Users for console and CLI, its better to create an IAM Group, attach MFA policy to this Group, then add all your IAM Users to the group. Must be done for each account of coarse in your organization.

The recommended policy is:

```
{
    "Sid": "BlockMostAccessUnlessSignedInWithMFA",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "NotAction":
    [
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
        "iam:ListAccountAliases",
        "iam:ListUsers",
        "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
        "iam:ListAccessKeys",
        "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
        "iam:ListMFADevices",
        "iam:GetAccountSummary",
        "sts:GetSessionToken"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition":
    {
        "BoolIfExists":
        {
            "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false",
            "aws:ViaAWSService": "false"
        }
    }
}
```

Using just "[Bool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-multifactorauthpresent)" can result in strange behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense, would this policy still work if I keep it as an SCP only and not as an IAM group policy?

Answer (score 0):

BoolifExists still not applies to the users whom comming from SSO, and whom assuming roles. STS is not seen by this SCP. and that is the main problem. It must deny all action except the notAction, whom does not have MFA. And should be allowed all users comming from specific source like SSO with correct permissionsets, when assuming roles specified in IIC.